# an urn containing 5 green and 2 red balls

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains 5 green and 2 red balls. One ball is drawn at random and its colour is recorded. This selected ball is then replaced in the urn and 3 more balls of the same colour are added to the urn. Next, another ball is drawn from the urn and its colour is recorded.

A) Find a suitable sample space for that random experiment and assign probabilities to sample points.

B) Find the probability distribution table of the random variable X representing the number of red balls among the two selected ones. Draw the bar chart of X.

C) Draw the cumulative distribution function F(x).

what are the answers for b and c?

Comment: The answers to B), C) follow from A).

Answer (score 2):

Sample space $\Omega = \{GG,GR, RG,RR\}$.

A)

[image]